# adding new data into the dependency array in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have two api calls trigger stdents info and failed students api response in the same time in react .

i have two api response in reducer  resultFailData and studentInfo.

both api depends with each other .

I try to add mobile number to resultFailData from studentInfo reducer data  and

try to add status column to studentInfo from the resultFailData data using below useEffect code.

this code have some issue it is working some time.

some times mobile number is not updated to resultFailData and status not updated to studentInfo, even it is updated it is not correctly render in the table.

Updated data i can able to see in console.log but it is not reflected in page(table rendered quickly before the set state happens)

```
useEffect(() => { 

    //  failed students data
    let resultFailData = reducerData?.resultFailData?.data;  
     // students data
    let studentInfo = reducerData?.studentData?.studentInfo?.data; 

    /**** Add parents mobile numbers to failed students data*******/
    if(resultFailData && resultFailData?.length > 0) {
      let result = resultFailData.map(item => {
         const secondItem = studentInfo && studentInfo.find(secondItem => secondItem.student_id === item.student_id);
           if(secondItem) {
            return {
             ...item,
             mobile: secondItem.phone
           };
          } else {
           return {
             ...item,
             mobile: ''
           };
         }
       }); 
       setresultFailData(result); 
    }  

    /**** Add status pass/fail to  students data*******/ 
    if(studentInfo && studentInfo?.length > 0) {  
     let result = reducerData?.studentData?.studentInfo?.data?.map(item => {
        if (resultFailData && resultFailData .some(secondItem => secondItem.student_id === item.student_id)) {
          return {
            ...item,
            status: "fail"
          };
        } else {
          return {
            ...item,
            status: "pass"
          };
        }
      });  
      setStudentData(result); 
    }


  },[
    reducerData.resultFailData,
    reducerData.studentData
  ]);
```

Note : studentData already have status field with default value as pass

Comment: Try adding these values in the dependency array
1. `reducerData?.resultFailData?.data `
2. reducerData?.studentData?.studentInfo?.data;

Comment: @NikhilTayal . added and tried . not working

Comment: Can you make a code sandbox online? It's hard to debug